# isinstance returning False when I expect it to return true

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am pretty new to Python. I'm just trying out a piece of code where the expected behaviour is:

It checks if an user input is an integer and if yes, outputs the square root of it. If not an integer, the system simply says its not an integer and does not do any calculation. Calculating the square root here is not important - I know there are inbuilt functions for calculating it, I am just practicing writing some lines of code.

However I have run into two problems

1. I'm trying to use ininstance to check whether the user input is really an integer. The problem is that the following check is returning a false even when I give an integer (say 64) as the input. I'm at a loss to understand why:

   ```py
   number1 = input("Please enter an integer ")
   print(number1)
   result = isinstance (number1, int)
   print(result)
   ```
2. Second is the IF Else loop. I defined a function SQUARE_ROOT(), and tried calling it only when the input is an integer. However, if the input is a string, e.g. "Sun"", the Else part is still executed and and returns a value error.

   > ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'sun'.

   I'm not sure what the issue here is again. I did try checking the indentation and does not seem very wrong to my rather inexperienced eyes

   ## funtion to output the squuare root of a number

   ```
    #import math
    #print("Please enter a number")

    def SQUARE_ROOT(number2):
        #Sq_root = math.pow(int(number2),0.5)
        Sq_root = int(number2)**0.5
        print(Sq_root)

    number1 = input("Please enter an integer ")
    print(number1)
    result = isinstance (number1, int)
    print(result)

    if(result == "False"):
        print("You have not entered an integer. the program will quit")
        #Print(quit)
        #sys.exit()
    else:
        print ("You have correctly entered an integer")
        SQUARE_ROOT(number1)
   ```

[image]

Comment: False shouldn't be inside quotes , i.e result==False instead of result=="False"

Comment: Please post the code as **text** (in a code block), do not use screenshots.

Comment: Also, `result` will always be False, because `input()` returns `str`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically in **Python 2.7**, we are having two ways to accepts inputs from the user.

**raw_input:**  always returns string

**input:**  Data & it's type get preserved.
So if user enters **1234** then the datatype would become **int** and if it's in string then str and so on.

[image]

Now Coming to the **Python 3.x**, function `raw_input` has been removed and `input` function behaviour get replaced with them.

In nutshell, everything that `input` function accepts and returns is of `str` type just like how the `raw_input` works in Py2.

[image]

Therefore, as per your question, the solution is you have to typecast after finding the types if its of desirable one. You may take help of `isdigit` method to know if its a number instead of using isinstance which would be true anyway once you convert them to `int`.

```
number1 = input("Please enter an integer ")
if number1.isdigit():    
    print ("You have correctly entered an integer")
    SQUARE_ROOT(int(number1))
else:
    print("You have not entered an integer. the program will quit")
    #Print(quit)
    #sys.exit()
```

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I did some more work and wanted to the code to handle the situation where the user could enter int or float or a string (by mistake). the code I have finally come up with is given below. gieven i am a beginner am sure this is not possibly the best way to write the code (i used while when i am not looping) but it does the job for now. thanks again

Answer (score 2):

when you are taking the input you are getting a string not an integer that's why it is returning false.

```
number1 = int(input("Please enter an integer "))
print(number1)
result = isinstance (number1, int)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your else is executing because if statement is not true because you are comparing string with boolean. To do so you have to either convert book to string or just remove quotes from false. And second thing is you have to convert your input from string format into integer then try calling is instance. Hopefully it should work then.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `int(...)` in the function but as @buran said `input(...)` returns string and you are asking if it's int. That is why it's returning `False`.

You can check that by adding `print(type(number1))` after the input.

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone for pointing me in the right direction. I did some more work and wanted to the code to handle the situation where the user could enter int or float or a string (by mistake). the code I have finally come up with is given below. gieven i am a beginner am sure this is not possibly the best way to write the code (i used while when i am not looping) but it does the job for now. thanks again

```
def SQUARE_ROOT(message):
    while True:
        try:
            number2 = float(message)      
        except ValueError:
            print("Not a number! The program will exit.")
            break
        else:
            Sq_root = float(number2)**0.5
            print("The square root of", number2, "ïs",Sq_root)
            print("Good Bye")
            break

userInput = input("PLease enter a number to get it's square root, or type exit ")

if userInput == "exit" :
    print ("Good Bye")
    
else :
    number1 = SQUARE_ROOT(userInput)
```